# A Query to return 2 values from 1 column based of other columns

Tags: mysql

I need to create an SQL query that returns multiple values from 1 column based off a value in that column and from other columns.
I have 2 tables, 
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KfBg.png)
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdIj1.png)

My current query is

```
SELECT title, id, value, item_id, catid, created, field_id, alias
FROM gewtk_content p
INNER JOIN gewtk_fields_values ON p.id = item_id
WHERE `value` = 'Jessica' AND `title` REGEXP '/ESD' 
AND `state` = '1' AND (`field_id` = '265' 
OR `field_id` = '297' OR `field_id` = '301' 
OR `field_id` = '301' OR `field_id` = '302' 
OR `field_id` = '303' OR `field_id` = '304')
```

which works as expected
But what I need is to also return the entry in the "value" column where field_id = 186 and the item_id entry that matches the item_id from the result of the above query. In this case the item_id = 532
So using the data in the tables and the above query the result would be

```html
<table style="height: 108px;" width="740">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 31px;">
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">title</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">id</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">value</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">item_id</td>
<td style="width: 75.7667px; height: 31px;">cat_id</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">created</td>
<td style="width: 75.7667px; height: 31px;">field_id</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 31px;">alias</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 39.7333px;">
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">positive/ESD</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">532</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">jessica</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">532</td>
<td style="width: 75.7667px; height: 39.7333px;">24</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">2019-04-03 05:41:3</td>
<td style="width: 75.7667px; height: 39.7333px;">265</td>
<td style="width: 75.7833px; height: 39.7333px;">positive-esd-18</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, I need to add to this the entry in the value column where field_id = 186 and item_id = 532 which is "Closed"
I cant see how this is possible as I need to show 2 entries from the value column in 1 row.

Comment: I hope those on the screenshots are fake data not real patient data.

Comment: Just sample data from a dev site

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table 1 a second time and add the second desired value with or-conjunction to the where-clause. Now you would receive two rows per query. To avoid this you can use [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) clause in the end. For the (result) column you would use concatenation. This is surely only one option, and I not sure if the best.

You could open a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some playing data that would make it easier to help you.